# Modulo 2 properties: $(-1)^{(x⊕a)∙y)}=1+(-1)^{a∙y)}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am looking at Quantum Physics solution for the Simon's problem.

In there there is equation for hadamard gate:

> [image: Blockquote]

I have trouble understanding the step: $(-1)^{(x⊕a)∙y)}=1+(-1)^{a∙y)}$

I was wondering if someone can point to general property of Modulo 2 that allows for the above equality.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the attached picture. The third line should have been written as:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n+1}}}\sum_{y=0}^{2^n-1} (-1)^{x'\bullet y} \color{red}{\cdot}(1+(-1)^{a\bullet y})|y\rangle$$

The above comes from the fact that the binary dot product distributes over the bitwise sum modulo $2$.

Comment: So:  $(x⊕a)∙y=(x∙y)∙(a∙y)$ for mod 2

Comment: @PhysicsQuestion $(x\oplus a)\cdot y = (x \cdot y) \oplus (a \cdot y)$

Comment: So can you exaplin the "???" part:  $(-1)^{(x⊕a)∙y}=(-1)^{(x∙y)⊕(a∙y)}=???..=(-1)^{(a∙y)}$

Comment: First of all it's easy to verify (casework) that $(-1)^{(x'\cdot y)\oplus (a\cdot y)} = (-1)^{x'\cdot y} (-1)^{a\cdot y}$. Then you just pull out the $(-1)^{x'\cdot y}$ as a common factor.